# How to change ordering of elements in a vector?

Tags: java

I have a vector of type Fruit. I can insert different types of fruits on my drawing canvas. If I have two overlapping fruits, I want to be able to raise the fruit after selecting it so that it now appears as if it is on top of the other fruit.

My basic idea for this is to have a raiseFruit() that is called after the jbutton is pressed. I create a temp variable set equal to the fruit that is selected, and then attempt to set it equal to the fruit at (a+1)...so the next position in the vector. And then I set this equal to temp variable. I think this is the right idea?

```
public void raiseFruit() { //raisefruit button
    if (_fruitIsSelected==true) {
        for (int i=0; i<_storedFruit.size() - 1; i++) {
            FunFruit a = _storedFruit.get(i);
            FunFruit b = _storedFruit.get(i + 1);
            if (_storedFruit.get(i+1)!=null) {
                FunFruit temp = a;
                _storedFruit.get(i) = _storedFruit.get(i+1);
                a=b;
                b = temp;
                //_storedShapes.setElementAt(_storedShapes.get(i+1), i);
                //_storedShapes.setElementAt(_currentShape, i+1);
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did try using setElementAt and it will work, but then if I press "raisefruit" again it will make the elements in front of it just entirely disappear. I just posted my code above with the part that keeps making elements in front of it disappear commented out. Instead of "a=b" I am trying to set whats in the vector at variable a equal to whats in the vector at variable b. Except, i keep getting an error that "left hand side must be a variable." Because I know that just setting a = to be just changes the pointers. I don't get how to actually change it inside the vector too, without the fruit elements in front being deleted.

Comment: Just curious, where did you learn to use a `Vector`? Are you sure that you aren't reading heavily outdated Java books/tutorials? A `Vector` is considered a legacy/obsolete class since over a decade.

Comment: Why is a vector considered as an obsolete class? I learned to use them in my AP computer science class in high school.

Comment: Vectors are certainly not obsolete. While their usefulness is as great as, say ArrayList, or objects obtained from the Collections class, they still have functionality not available in other similar classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reassigning your temporary variable instead of the list. use

```
_fruits.setElementAt(fruit, index);
```

to set elements in the list instead of

```
_fruits.get(_currentSelectedFruit + 1) = temp;
```

in which you are just taking the pointer returned by get and assigning it to temp